# Listing users from Database using Node.js and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to load data from my database named `users` which contains `2` users in the collection named `userlist`. Each entry has a name and age.

The code below resides in my **app.js**.

```js
//set database connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users');
mongoose.connection.on('error',function(){
   console.log('MongoDB Connection Error. Please make sure that MongoDB is running');
    process.exit(1);
});
mongoose.connection.once('open',function(callback){
   console.log('Connected to Database');
   
});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name:{type:String,uppercase:true},
   age:Number
});

var userModel = mongoose.model('userModel',userSchema);

app.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  userModel.find({},function(err,userModel){
      res.send(userModel);
         
      //Have tried res.send(userlist) also

  })
});
```

This returns an empty set `[]` on `localhost:3000/users`. However i do have two entries in my database.

Comment: What do you see when you inspect `userModel`?

Comment: Seems your collection name is different in your code and your database.

Comment: @JyotmanSingh could you please point out where?

Comment: declare your schema and mongoose.model before the mongoose connection

Comment: can you check if you are able to get data from other collections? also try consoling the data `console.log(userModel)`

Comment: `mongoose.model('userModel',userSchema);` - This line is used to create your collection which will create it by the name `usermodels` I think. Best way would be to insert a document using mongoose and see what collection is formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name:{type:String,uppercase:true},
   age:Number
},{collection:'userlist'});
```

This is what helped me.